# Replace String in Spark Dataframe based on Map of Regex with its replacements + SCALA

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, replace

I have DataFrame as below.

```
+-----------------------------------+
|mycol                              |
+-----------------------------------+
|12 https://jhafi.com xyza@gmail.com|
|12 https://jhafi.com xyza@gmail.com|
|12 https://jhafi.com xyza@gmail.com|
|12 https://jhafi.com xyza@gmail.com|
+-----------------------------------+
```

I have replacement Map as below.

```
Map( PHTEXTEMAIL  -> """(?i)\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b""" , PHTEXTURL -> "(^|\\W)(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\\/\\/|www\\.|ftp\\.)(?:\\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\\/%=~_|$])($|\\W)", PHTEXTEMAIL  -> """(?i)\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b""")
```

Now I want to iterate this Map of replacement and want to apply the same on my data frame.

Expected DataFrame.

```
+------------------------+
|mycol                   |
+------------------------+
|12 PHTEXTURL PHTEXTEMAIL|
|12 PHTEXTURL PHTEXTEMAIL|
|12 PHTEXTURL PHTEXTEMAIL|
|12 PHTEXTURL PHTEXTEMAIL|
+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Its quit straight forward with `regexp_replace` function.

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq("12 https://jhafi.com xyza@gmail.com",
  "12 https://jhafi.com xyza@gmail.com",
  "12 https://jhafi.com xyza@gmail.com",
  "12 https://jhafi.com xyza@gmail.com").toDF("mycol")


val email = """(?i)\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b"""
val url ="(https?:\\/\\/(?:www\\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.[^\\s]{2,}|www\\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.[^\\s]{2,}|https?:\\/\\/(?:www\\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[^\\s]{2,}|www\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[^\\s]{2,})"

val urlRegexExpression = regexp_replace($"mycol", url, "PHTEXTURL")
val emailRegexExpression = regexp_replace($"mycol", email, "PHTEXTEMAIL")

df.withColumn("mycol", emailRegexExpression).withColumn("mycol", urlRegexExpression).show(false)
```

**Output**

```
+------------------------+
|mycol                   |
+------------------------+
|12 PHTEXTURL PHTEXTEMAIL|
|12 PHTEXTURL PHTEXTEMAIL|
|12 PHTEXTURL PHTEXTEMAIL|
|12 PHTEXTURL PHTEXTEMAIL|
+------------------------+
```

**Note :**

I made changes to your URL regex as it was not working.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: This pattern can be not one or two.. it can be any number . so we can not do like this. we have to have for loop or any other approach to do so. i would appriciate if you can suggest something. its still open.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :)

```
import sparkSession.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{udf, col}

def patterns_replace(patterns: Map[String, String]) = udf((text: String) =>
  patterns.foldLeft(text) { case (text, (replacement, pattern)) =>
    text.replaceAll(pattern, replacement)
  }
)

val df = Seq(
  "12 https://jhafi.com xyza@gmail.com",
  "12 https://jhafi.com xyza@gmail.com",
  "12 https://jhafi.com xyza@gmail.com",
  "12 https://jhafi.com xyza@gmail.com"
).toDF("input")

val patterns = Map(
  "EMAIL" -> "[a-z]+@gmail.com",
  "URL" -> "https://[a-z]+\\.com"
)

df.withColumn("output", patterns_replace(patterns)(col("input")))
```

Output

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+
|input                              |output      |
+-----------------------------------+------------+
|12 https://jhafi.com xyza@gmail.com|12 URL EMAIL|
|12 https://jhafi.com xyza@gmail.com|12 URL EMAIL|
|12 https://jhafi.com xyza@gmail.com|12 URL EMAIL|
|12 https://jhafi.com xyza@gmail.com|12 URL EMAIL|
+-----------------------------------+------------+
```